# Embedded select with rank

Tags: mysql

I am having the hardest time following the tutorials on this site regarding ranking with MySQL.  I have a larger problem than others seem to show.
My table is constantly updating with single answers (`ans`) corresponding to a matching word (`word`).  I also have to check whether the row has an answer at all (`ans IS NOT NULL`).

I've devised the following:

```
SELECT userid, floor(sum(ans = word) / count(id) * 100) as score
FROM fb_asl.quiz
WHERE DATE(`time`) BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL (-3) DAY AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL (-3) DAY
AND ans IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This returns the following

```
1504    93
3567    79
8225    66
```

How can I go about getting a rank corresponding to a specific `userid`?  Say returning something like:

```
2   3567    79
```

Comment: How should the case of `93, 79, 79, 66` be ranked? Should it be *a)* `1, 2, 3, 4`, *b)* `1, 2, 2, 4`, or *c)* `1, 2, 2, 3`? If *a)*, how should the query determine which `userid` must be assigned which ranking in case of ties?

Comment: And by the way, you could simplify the `score` expression a little: `floor(avg(100 * (ans = word))) as score`.

Comment: Andriy M, that's a good point.  I'm indifferent between a) 1, 2, 3, 4, b) 1, 2, 2, 4.  I guess in the case of a) I'll let the userid sort ASC.
Also thanks for the tip on avg().  I completely forgot about that function.

Comment: There are many suggestions in [this thread](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table "Get the rank of a user in a score table").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the above query, I have a solution for you

```
SET @rnk=0; SET @rank=0; SET @curscore=0;
SELECT score,userid,rank FROM
(
SELECT AA.*,
    (@rnk:=@rnk+1) rnk,
    (@rank:=IF(@curscore=score,@rank,@rnk)) rank,
    (@curscore:=score) newscore
FROM
(
    SELECT
        userid,
        floor(sum(ans = word) / count(id) * 100) as score
    FROM fb_asl.quiz
    WHERE
        DATE(`time`) BETWEEN
        CURDATE() + INTERVAL (-3) DAY AND
        AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL (-3) DAY
        AND ans IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY userid
) AA ORDER BY score DESC) A;
```

Let me demonstrate it with some sample data

## SAMPLE DATA

```
use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS scores;
CREATE TABLE scores
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    score int not null,
    primary key (id),
    key score (score)
);
INSERT INTO scores (score) VALUES
(50),(40),(75),(80),(55),
(40),(30),(80),(70),(45),
(40),(30),(65),(70),(45),
(55),(45),(83),(85),(60);
```

## SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS scores;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE scores
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     score int not null,
    ->     primary key (id),
    ->     key score (score)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO scores (score) VALUES
    -> (50),(40),(75),(80),(55),
    -> (40),(30),(80),(70),(45),
    -> (40),(30),(65),(70),(45),
    -> (55),(45),(83),(85),(60);
Query OK, 20 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 20  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

## WHAT SAMPLE DATA LOOKS LIKE

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM scores;
+----+-------+
| id | score |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    50 |
|  2 |    40 |
|  3 |    75 |
|  4 |    80 |
|  5 |    55 |
|  6 |    40 |
|  7 |    30 |
|  8 |    80 |
|  9 |    70 |
| 10 |    45 |
| 11 |    40 |
| 12 |    30 |
| 13 |    65 |
| 14 |    70 |
| 15 |    45 |
| 16 |    55 |
| 17 |    45 |
| 18 |    83 |
| 19 |    85 |
| 20 |    60 |
+----+-------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## MY SOLUTION AGAINST THE SAMPLE DATA

```
SET @rnk=0; SET @rank=0; SET @curscore=0;
SELECT score,ID,rank FROM
(
    SELECT AA.*,BB.ID,
    (@rnk:=@rnk+1) rnk,
    (@rank:=IF(@curscore=score,@rank,@rnk)) rank,
    (@curscore:=score) newscore
    FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT COUNT(1) scorecount,score
        FROM scores GROUP BY score
    ) AAA
    ORDER BY score DESC
) AA LEFT JOIN scores BB USING (score)) A;
```

## MY SOLUTION EXECUTED AGAINST THE SAMPLE DATA

```
mysql> SELECT score,ID,rank FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT AA.*,BB.ID,
    ->     (@rnk:=@rnk+1) rnk,
    ->     (@rank:=IF(@curscore=score,@rank,@rnk)) rank,
    ->     (@curscore:=score) newscore
    ->     FROM
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT * FROM
    ->         (SELECT COUNT(1) scorecount,score
    ->         FROM scores GROUP BY score
    ->     ) AAA
    ->     ORDER BY score DESC
    -> ) AA LEFT JOIN scores BB USING (score)) A;
+-------+------+------+
| score | ID   | rank |
+-------+------+------+
|    85 |   19 |    1 |
|    83 |   18 |    2 |
|    80 |    4 |    3 |
|    80 |    8 |    3 |
|    75 |    3 |    5 |
|    70 |    9 |    6 |
|    70 |   14 |    6 |
|    65 |   13 |    8 |
|    60 |   20 |    9 |
|    55 |    5 |   10 |
|    55 |   16 |   10 |
|    50 |    1 |   12 |
|    45 |   10 |   13 |
|    45 |   15 |   13 |
|    45 |   17 |   13 |
|    40 |    2 |   16 |
|    40 |    6 |   16 |
|    40 |   11 |   16 |
|    30 |    7 |   19 |
|    30 |   12 |   19 |
+-------+------+------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Maybe there's no need to write another answer. There've been quite a few already, yours included. Since you've got enough reputation, you could just suggest closing this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @AndriyM I am going to delete my old answer because nobody has upvoted it and my answer handles ties and consecutive ranking differently from the others. Thus, I am migrating that answer away from that old question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA why do you always think that because an answer hasn't been up-voted it should be deleted? Answers can still be useful to people - especially yours, since they're so detailed - including to people who come here anonymously or don't yet have enough reputation to vote.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think I'm kind of influenced by two posts in Meta StackOverflow: 1) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108150 ,  2) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47584. Even though these two posts discuss retiring questions, I was having mixed feelings about my answers in this respect. Actually, I wasn't sure if my answers were helpful to anyone.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I'd assume they're helpful (or may be helpful in the future) unless you have concrete evidence of the opposite. You can't measure helpfulness by solely looking at up-votes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you just gave an idea. Perhaps I can post something in DBA Meta about displaying info concerning anonymous users and a post's helpfulness to them. I'll post such a question sometime this week.

Comment: @Rolando: [you might find this interesting](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits?userid=877)

Comment: @Shog9 That's very interesting. That's more-or-less what I was thinking.

Comment: I assume you've already seen this, but worth remembering: http://dba.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/underrated?filter=all

Comment: @Shog9 Are you kidding me ? No, I was not aware of this. Thank you, because I was going to write a post in DBA Meta asking something like this. I see `review chat meta faq` next to my name. How do I click this?

Comment: If you click "review" then "tools" it'll be a link titled "anonymous and low rep post feedback" on the resulting page.

Comment: Rolando, works like a charm!  Thank you all so much for your help.  So much great information on this page.