# Rank variable value in MySQL is always being set to null

Tags: mysql

In a sample procedure I am trying to find the rank the of the cities according to the 
    number of offices. I have a Location Table and an Office Table and a location can have 
    multiple offices ( In my case I am assuming Boston has 3 offices and Bangalore has only
    2) offices and I want them to rank accordingly . I am using the below SP but it returns
    me the rank as 0 and 0 and also MySQL query browser is being crashed . I guess I am
    making some error here .

```
   BEGIN

   DECLARE rank INT DEFAULT 0;

   SELECT rank =rank+1 AS Rank,l.Location_Name,COUNT(*)
   AS Number_Of_Offices FROM employee_leaves_management_system.location l
   INNER JOIN
   employee_leaves_management_system.office o
   ON l.Location_ID = o.Office_Location_ID
   GROUP BY l.Location_Name
   ORDER BY Number_Of_Offices;

   END $$
```

A quick help will be much appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

= is the assignement operator only for SET statements,in your case is a comparison operator,for SELECT use `rank := rank+1`

Example

```
SET @var=1;
SELECT @var = 1 + 1; -> This compares @var which is one to 2 so it returns 0.
```

Result 0

```
SET @var=1;
SELECT @var := 1 + 1; -> This actually adds up.
```

Result 2

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to the forums. In future could you please provide DDL (run the SHOW CREATE TABLE employee_leaves_management_system.location\G (&c.) and also DML (INSERT INTO employee_leaves_management_system.location VALUES(...)) so that those who wish to help you can easily test solutions. See [here](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/) (and links within) on useful tips on asking questions.

As to your question, you could take a look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74872/retrieving-row-ranking-in-a-table/74886?noredirect=1#comment135159_74886) for a pure SQL solution to a ranking query (the OP's original SQL is actually correct for his problem, can't tell if it will be for yours).