# Get the rank of a row based on a score I am generating from other field values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how I can get the rank of a row from a score I am generating from other field values.

The score query looks something like this

```
SELECT ((table2.field1*0.4) + (table2.field2 * 0.2) + (table1.field1*0.7)) 'score' FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.table1_id=table1.id GROUP BY table1.table1_id ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

This generates my scores, they look something like this

```
|4363.195
|3970.4210000000003
|2781.8
|2601.2980000000002
|2508.905
|2269.829
|2204.1
|1893.367
|1789.575
```

I am trying to get rank of each provider in a query like this

```
SELECT rank_here, table2.* FROM `table2` WHERE 1
```

This is just sample stuff I am just trying to figure out how to do this(this is why I have also included the score being generated from 2 tables, but it really doesn't matter it can be from a single table or even more than 2)

I researched :
[Get the rank of a user in a score table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table)

But all I found is how to get the rank if I have the score in a field, and in my case I need to make it based on other field values.

Comment: You do know that you can use a subquery in the `from` clause?

Comment: `ON table2.table1_id=table2.id` doesn't look right.

Comment: @ypercube sorry fixed now, I wrote the queries here, as I said I just want the method of doing this.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I do know but I don't know how that would help me ? I am really a newbie in mysql sorry :(

Comment: It helps because you can treat your query as the table that you "plugin" to any of the queries in the answer you quoted, eg `SET @i=0;
SELECT id, name, score, @i:=@i+1 AS rank 
 FROM (<your_query>) ranking 
 ORDER BY score DESC;` to use one of the answers as an example.

Comment: Or you can repeat your expression (`table2.field1*0.4 + table2.field2*0.2 + table1.field1*0.7`) wherever you would use the `score` column. (Note that you don't need any of the brackets either due to operator precedence.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 1, 2, 3, ... tacked onto the output?

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1,
       s.*
    FROM ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) AS init
    JOIN (
        SELECT ... -- your existing SELECT
         ) s;
```