# How to get latest 2 records of each group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, rank

So, I have table similar to:

```
sn color value
1  red   4
2  red   8
3  green 5
4  red   2
5  green 4
6  green 3
```

Now I need the latest 2 rows for each color, eg:

```
2  red   8
4  red   2
5  green 4
6  green 3
```

How to do it, other than using separate query for each color?

Thanks

Comment: The latest according to `sn`? And which version of MySQL?

Comment: yes according to sn

Comment: Is `sn` unique or the primary key?

Comment: sn is primary key, but in future I would like to do it through time column which may not be unique

Comment: you can use RANK() here

Comment: @EdgarAllanBayron if you're on mysql 8

Comment: @EdgarAllanBayron will using rank be faster than running 1 query for each color (color count around 15) and total 100000 records in table

Comment: @lost111in yes, it'll all be faster and more sane if you migrate to PostgreSQL. =)

Comment: More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 3):

### With MySQL 8

```
SELECT sn, color, value
FROM (
  SELECT
    sn,
    color,
    value,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY sn) AS r
  FROM table
) AS t
WHERE t.r <= 2;
```

### Using MySQL < 8

You need to use their special variables.. [something like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41483/2639)

Comment: using MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 so getting error

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on the "greatest-n-per-group" problem. It could be used with window functions or `LATERAL` joins (also known as `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`), if only MySQL had implemented them<sup>*</sup>.

Here's one method that works. I call it "poor man's cross apply":

```
select t.*
from 
    ( select distinct color from tbl ) as td    -- for every colour
  left join                                     -- join to the table
    tbl as t                                    -- and get all rows
  on  t.color = td.color                        -- with that color
  and t.sn >= coalesce(                         -- and sn bigger or equal than
      ( select ti.sn                            -- the 2nd higher sn value
        from tbl as ti
        where ti.color = td.color
        order by ti.sn desc
        limit 1 offset 1                        -- 1 + 1st = 2nd
      ), -9223372036854775808    -- the smallest possible bigint value,
          ) ;                    -- to cover cases of colours 
                                 -- with a single appearance, where
                                 -- the subquery returns NULL
```

Tested in [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=3856fd47b3f9cc2127303e5380044c9a). An index on `(color, sn)` or `(color, sn, value)` will be used by this query. If there are only a few distinct `color` values, it is quite efficient.

<sup>*</sup>: MariaDB, a fork of MySQL has indeed implemented window functions, so a solution with a ranking function, like `ROW_NUMBER()`, `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` would work there.

Comment: The MySQL solution to this problem typically uses their special variables to create rank.

Comment: @EvanCarroll yeah, I variables can be used, too. I prefer this method. There's also a method that (ab)uses `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: Works, however taking 15 seconds on average

Comment: @lost111in share the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname;` if you like. Do you have or did you add an index on `(color, sn)`? What's the size of the table (number of rows)? How many distinct colors?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks, I have separate index on color and sn, around 20k rows and 10 colors, however ended by using https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198712/

Comment: I suggested one composite index, not 2 indexes. Of course you are free to use whatever method you prefer. Don't forget to test them ;)

Comment: With so small tables and so few distinct colours, I would expect this query to be much faster, no more than a few tens of milliseconds really.