# Variable value is not incrementing

Tags: mysql

Why is the country_rank value 1 for each row, which I assume is due to STRCMP returing false everytime. I think @current_country is not set correctly but dont know why.

Table:

```
sn country city
1  AAA     aaa
2  BBB     bbb
3  AAA     ccc
```

Output Expected:

```
country city country_rank
AAA     ccc  1
AAA     aaa  2
BBB     bbb  1
```

Query:

```
SELECT country,city,
@country_rank := IF(STRCMP(country,@current_country) = 0,  @country_rank + 1, 1) AS country_rank,
@current_country := country
FROM table  
ORDER BY country,sn  DESC
```

The query is supposed to rank the cities in each country as per sn.
MYSQL 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT country,city,
       @country_rank :=
          IF(STRCMP(country,@current_country) = 0,  @country_rank + 1, 1)
          AS country_rank,
       @current_country := country  setctry
  FROM  cities,
        (select @current_country="", @country_rank=0) init
  ORDER BY country,sn  DESC
```

cfr. SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c388ef7/2