# How to get the latest LastUpdate ,LocReqNo of each locationID of MySQL queryautoricardo.ch - Fahrzeugmarkt – Apps bei Google Play

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.7, greatest-n-per-group

As I want to retrieve the LastUpdate , LocReqNo of every location.
I mean to say that in the mention table there is 3 locationId , i.e., A1,A2,A3.

[image]

I want the output of the above table as follows:

[image]

I have gone through [How to get latest 2 records of each group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198697/how-to-get-latest-2-records-of-each-group) , but unable to get my expected result.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: what MySQL version?

Comment: @danblack, MySQL version is  5.7.

Comment: See the tag I added.

Comment: @RickJames, Yes Rick ,I have missed to add that tag. Thanks for notify and it's accepted.