# how to get rank number that group by a column

Tags: mysql, rank

I spend hours trying to solve this, but I can't.

Well, I simply have a table call **invoices**

I have data like this

[image]

I want to know each customer rank by their total sum

How can I archive this?

Comment: Nothing against McNets ' solution below, but you can find a number of answers to this basic question on the site, simply by searching for `MySQL rank`. [This one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table) includes a number of possible options, depending on how you want to handle customers whose sums come out to be the same. I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of the one to which I've linked.

Comment: Actually, I have read lot of those but it did't answer my need. I just want to get a single rank value from a list rank value. When I tried those solutions, it is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable for this purpose.

> ```
> select customer_id, total, rank
> from (
>       select customer_id, total, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
>       from (
>             select customer_id, sum(total) total
>             from   invoices
>             group by customer_id
>             order by sum(total) desc
>            ) t1, (select @rank := 0) t2
>      ) t3
> where customer_id = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> customer_id | total | rank
> ----------: | ----: | ---:
>           1 | 14080 |    2
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1c7a23334b59f96445af9f8752bd91ee)*

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However, if I want to get the rank of customer_id = 1 which should return 2, how can I do that? 

I try to "where customer_id = 1" after your command but it seems not working since it returns 1 instead

Comment: Done but it's a lot of work, worth it?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very very much.