# MySQL Query to get rank of a student

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `score` (
    `sid` INT NULL,
    `name` INT NULL,
    `rollno` INT NULL,
    `examid` INT NULL,
    `phone` INT NULL,
    `dob` INT NULL,
    `district` INT NULL,
    `score` INT NULL,
    `active` INT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I need a query that will assign rank to a student based on their score and age. If two students have same mark, student with highest date of birth is given priority.

**This is the sample data I have:**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sid | name | examid | phone | dob       | district | score | date       | active 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     User1    1      12345  10/11/1983   209         10     10/11/2017     1

2     User2    1      34567  11/10/1983   209         10     10/11/2017     1

3     User3    1      34567  11/10/1985   209         20     10/11/2017     1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The result I am expecting is like this:**

```
+----+------------------+----------------+
| id | name             |           rank |
+----+------------------+----------------+
|  2 |           User2  |              1 |
|  3 |           User3  |              2 |
|  2 |           User1  |              3 |
```

My question is similar to this question ([Get the rank of a user in a score table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table))  but is there any other solution.

This is the current query I have which is working but how to display rank with the same query.

```
SELECT name, rollno, score
FROM score
WHERE examid = '1'
ORDER BY score DESC, dob ASC
```

Comment: Please consider reading the following articles: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_ and _[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) (Meta DBA.SE)_. Currently your question doesn't contain enough information and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). (TL;DR: Could you please supply some sample data, sample results, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of MySQL you can use a window function:

```
SELECT name, rollno, score
     , rank() over (order by score, dob desc) as rnk
FROM score
WHERE examid = '1'
ORDER BY score DESC, dob ASC
```

rank() will use gaps in case of a draw (1,1,3,...), use dense_rank() for 1,1,2,...

For older version you can count the number of scores less or equal to current score

```
SELECT name, rollno, score
     , (select count(1) + 1 from score s2
        where s2.score > s1.score
           or (s2.score = s1.score and s2.dob < s1.dob)) as rnk
FROM score s1
WHERE examid = '1'
ORDER BY score DESC, dob ASC
```

Comment: When I use the second query rank count starts from 0.

Comment: just add 1 to the count, I'll update

Comment: You can also add 1 outside of the sub-select: `, (...) + 1 as rnk`

Comment: I have updated the query and it is now working.

Comment: For the query to work I have to replace '<' with '>'

Comment: Thanks, I'll update. Is it the one in `and s2.dob < s1.dob`?

Comment: I replaced  s2.score < s1.score with s2.score > s1.score and it sorted data based on highest score and dob

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8+

```
SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score ASC, dob DESC) rank
FROM score
```

MySQL 5+

```
SELECT id, name, @rank := @rank + 1 rank
FROM score, (SELECT @rank := 0) init
ORDER BY score ASC, dob DESC
```

The students with equal both score and birth will be ranked randomly.