# Getting Ranked Position - SQL - Simple Query

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple database structure and am struggling to write a command to find the ranked position of the user.

```sql
------------------
id     |  average
------------------
1      |  79
------------------
2      |  99
------------------
3      |  22
```

How would I be able to find the ranked position of the user with id 1? #2 would be ranked 1st. I want the rank to be descending with the highest number in 1st place.

Comment: Please, tag your MySQL version. Latest versions allow to use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) like RANK()

Comment: If you could provide more information about the data you are looking at and what you have tried so far it would help

Answer (score 0):

If you are in version 8 (or above), you can use the RANK() function for this purpose:

```
SELECT
    id,
    average,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY average DESC) as rk
FROM
    t;
```

Note I've ordered the result by `average DESC`, that assigns rank=1 to the maximum average.

> ```
> id | average | rk
> -: | ------: | -:
>  2 |      99 |  1
>  1 |      79 |  2
>  3 |      22 |  3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cbf1f590078fd85bb5018166be95e34)*

Answer (score -2):

assuming `average` is the column name -

add 
`order by Average Desc` on the end of your query

have a look at [the answers to this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13703/22336) for further information

Comment: Could you provide an example? I am not sure how that might work.

Comment: This answer is pretty similar - 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table?rq=1